# OpenVPN client connected but can't access internal websites

Tags: 18.04, openvpn

I am trying to connect to my company's VPN server.

```
▶ sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn --auth-user-pass --auth-retry interact
```

`client.ovpn` is downloaded from the OpenVPN server. The same file works on my OSX with openVPN client. So I am assuming `client.ovpn` is all fine.

After I connect, this is what I see on the terminal (few parts omitted):

```
Thu Nov 15 01:58:24 2018 us=369587 Option 'explicit-exit-notify' in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:1 is ignored by previous <connection> blocks 
Thu Nov 15 01:58:24 2018 us=369660 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:4: dhcp-pre-release (2.4.4)
Thu Nov 15 01:58:24 2018 us=369699 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:5: dhcp-renew (2.4.4)
Thu Nov 15 01:58:24 2018 us=369731 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:6: dhcp-release (2.4.4)
Thu Nov 15 01:58:24 2018 us=370033 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:31: register-dns (2.4.4)
Thu Nov 15 01:58:24 2018 us=370068 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:32: block-ipv6 (2.4.4)
............
............
............
Thu Nov 15 01:58:29 2018 us=641193 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

`ifconfig` shows the following interface:

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.227.152  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 172.27.227.152
        inet6 fe80::d604:d89a:a84a:3bc9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3  bytes 144 (144.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I am unable to browse the internal website after this. I am able to access other websites. There are no error reported in OpenVPN.

How can I fix this?

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

OpenVPN version says the following:

```
▶ openvpn --version 
OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Sep  5 2018
library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017, LZO 2.08
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2017 OpenVPN Technologies, Inc. <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_async_push=no enable_comp_stub=no enable_crypto=yes enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes enable_dependency_tracking=no enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=needless enable_fragment=yes enable_iproute2=yes enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lz4=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_maintainer_mode=no enable_management=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=yes enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=no enable_server=yes enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_silent_rules=no enable_small=no enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=yes enable_werror=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_aix_soname=aix with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_mem_check=no with_sysroot=no
```

Comment: Can you write first line of output: `openvpn --version` please

Comment: Again: You cant access "internal" sites only? What you mean when told "internal sites"?

Comment: @S_Flash Edited my post to add the openvpn version. When I say internal websites, I mean all the websites that work only on VPN are not working.

Comment: Please try run first: `traceroute 172.217.20.78` (one of google server IP) then `traceroute google.com`. In case first will work with no errors and second with errors, you have troubles with OpenVPN DNS. In your log i see warnings when server try to push this settings to your client.

Comment: @S_Flash Thanks a lot for taking time to look into it. Both traceroute finished without errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try edit your OpenVPN client config with adding:

```
# Set CloudFlare and Google DNS:
dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
```

And reconnect. If no effect, edit config again and replace lines above with:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

^ Be sure both settings examples not included in your client config first.

(It will be better previously to be sure that file `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` exist in your OS. Example: `ls /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` or `cat /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf`)

Comment: Bothe the options are not helping. 

Fri Nov 16 22:08:02 2018 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:4: dhcp-pre-release (2.4.4)
Fri Nov 16 22:08:02 2018 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:5: dhcp-renew (2.4.4)
Fri Nov 16 22:08:02 2018 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:6: dhcp-release (2.4.4)

Looks like it is DNS issues as you have suspected. Do you think it is a server config issue?

Comment: Server continue push troubles with unrecognized options. If you have no access to server config, just ignore old log messages.